# I want to update a dictionary/json key instead of appending a new one?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Alright, So I am using discord.py and JSON and I am trying to make a ticket counter, the client refuses to use a database so I have to use JSON. But every time the code updates the file it create a second key and then it uses that key instead of the first one. If anyone wants to see it happen in action friend me (Jpac14#8237) and I'll show you what happens. I will also attach my code and the JSON file.

Also do you think I could you Collections Module for this.

Code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import json

class TicketSystem(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.create_ticket_msgs = []

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
        for create_ticket_msg in self.create_ticket_msgs:
            if reaction.message.id == create_ticket_msg.id and user != self.bot.user:
                await reaction.message.channel.send(f"{user} reacted")
                await reaction.message.remove_reaction("", user)

                ticket_counter_dict = {}

                try:
                    with open("json/ticket_counter.json", "r") as ticket_counter_json:
                        ticket_counter_dict = json.load(ticket_counter_json)
                except json.JSONDecodeError:
                    print("JSONDecodeError")

                current_ticket_counter = ticket_counter_dict.get(str(reaction.message.guild.id))

                if current_ticket_counter == None:
                    current_ticket_counter = 1

                ticket_catergory = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.guild.categories, name="Tickets")

                if reaction.message.guild.id == 660156957486874645:
                    support_team_role = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.guild.roles, name="Staff")
                else:
                    support_team_role = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.guild.roles, name="Support")

                ticket_channel_overwrites = {
                    support_team_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
                    user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
                    reaction.message.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)
                }

                users_ticket_channel = await ticket_catergory.create_text_channel(f"ticket-{current_ticket_counter}", overwrites=ticket_channel_overwrites)

                current_ticket_counter += 1

                ticket_counter_dict.update({reaction.message.guild.id: current_ticket_counter})

                with open("json/ticket_counter.json", "w") as ticket_counter_json:
                    json.dump(ticket_counter_dict, ticket_counter_json)

                embedMessage = discord.Embed(description="Support will be with you shortly.\nTo close the ticket type ?close", color=discord.colour.Colour.green())
                embedMessage.set_footer(text=f"Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

                await users_ticket_channel.send(embed=embedMessage)



    @commands.command(name="ticketmsg")
    async def send_create_ticket_msg(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
        embedMessage = discord.Embed(title="Create A Ticket", description="To create a ticket react with ", timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=discord.colour.Colour.green())
        embedMessage.set_footer(text=f"Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

        create_ticket_msg = await channel.send(embed=embedMessage)
        await create_ticket_msg.add_reaction("")

        self.create_ticket_msgs.append(create_ticket_msg)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TicketSystem(bot))
```

JSON File:

```
{"665930890039394305": 6, "665930890039394305": 7}
```

Comment: this is illustrating a really interesting caveat of the `json` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reaction.message.guild.id` is an `int`.

When you write `ticket_counter_dict.update({reaction.message.guild.id: current_ticket_counter})`, you create a new `int` key in your dict, which doesn't override the `str` key that exists from loading the `json` file.

See this example:

```py
import json
d = {1: 'a', '1': 'b'}
json.dumps(d)
>>> '{"1": "b", "1": "a"}'
```

The dict can hold both `1` and `'1'` as keys as they are different objects. But the json serialization will turn both into strings, as json uses strings as keys.

I supposed there is room for improvement in the json module as it doesn't seem to check that the stringified keys are all unique.

You can fix your code by making sure you use a string for the key in your dict:

```
ticket_counter_dict.update({str(reaction.message.guild.id): current_ticket_counter})
```

Comment: Can I use `dictionary[str(key)] = value` and it will also work?